# Sent wallet to desktop

Tags: wallet

I had bitcoin core and dummy me deleted it but I sent my wallet to desktop and now I have a new wallet, are there any way to get the wallet that is on my desktop back into bitcoin core? I tried to copy and paste but that does not work. I went to %APPDATA%\roaming\bitcoin but could not do a copy and paste into it. Any way to get my wallet back into it.
Thanks for your time.
RoberT

Comment: What problem do you have when you copy and paste?  Does the file not copy, or does the wallet file not load when you restart Bitcoin Core?

Comment: The file does not copy,I am reindexing now for a new wallet.

Comment: Make sure that Bitcoin Core is not running when you attempt to copy, otherwise it may have a hold on the file.  Also make sure you are running as a user with sufficient permissions to copy over the other wallet file.  It sounds like it's your operating system that is not allowing you to copy...not Bitcoin.